# print multiple patterns with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed, pattern-matching

I try to print multiple patterns with sed.

Here's a typical string to process :

```
(<span class="arabic">1</span>.<span class="arabic">15</span>)</td></tr>
```

and I would like : `(1.15)`

For this, I tried :

```
sed 's/^(<span.*">\([0-9]*\).*\([0-9]*\).*">/(\1\.\2)/'
```

but I get `(1.)15</span>)</td></tr>`

Anyone could see what's wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: HTML parsing with REGEX spotted ! Dude, don't do this using REGEX, use a proper HTML parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reason why you are getting "(1.)15) as your output"**

```
sed 's/^(<span.*">\([0-9]*\).*\([0-9]*\).*">/(\1\.\2)/'
                                          ^^
```

the two characters `">` needs to be placed before `\([0-9]*\)` since `">` in your line is before the two digits (in this case). This way sed can find the pattern

**The correct sed command**

```
sed 's/^(<span.*">\([0-9]*\).*">\([0-9]*\).*/(\1.\2)/'
                              ^^
```

**Correct Command line**

```
echo '(<span class="arabic">1</span>.<span class="arabic">15</span>)</td></tr>'|sed 's/^(<span.*">\([0-9]*\).*">\([0-9]*\).*/(\1.\2)/'
```

results using the command line above

```
(1.15)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. does ".*' mean all characters and include also > and " characters ? in other words, is it including special characters ?

Comment: .* means ALL characters including > and " to up to the pattern for example (.*">) means all characters up to the pattern ">

Comment: ok, so from I have understood, I have to indicate the characters preceding the pattern, i.e in my example, the characters "> ?

Comment: You can if all your lines are the same you can type each character upto ">. but in this case, I use .*"> because I don't know what characters are before the pattern ">. However I do know that "> is a pattern found on every line. As a result I match all characters upto ">

Answer (score 1):

If **you are Chuck Norris, use [regex](/questions/tagged/regex)**, [brainfuck](/questions/tagged/brainfuck) or [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly). If you're not, **don't use regex to parse HTML**, instead, use a tool that support [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath), like [xmllint](/questions/tagged/xmllint). In 2014, it's a solved problem :

```
xmllint --html --xpath '//span[@class="arabic"]/text()' file_or_URL
```

Check the famous [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

`xmllint` comes from `libxml2-utils` package (for debian and derivatives)

Comment: you should add some cthulhu reference and bleeding fonts :)

Comment: You mean this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags
DONE

Comment: Actually Chuck Norris can parse HTML with regex

Comment: Yes, Chuck Norris can, others shouldn't =)

Answer (score 0):

If data is at the same place all the time, `awk` may be a simpler solution than `sed`:

```
awk -F"[<>]" '{print "("$3"."$7")"}' file
(1.15)
```

Comment: HTML can change, it's inpredictable in general

Answer (score -1):

```
$ lynx -dump -nomargins file.htm
(1.15)
```

Comment: Not that bad if the HTML contains only the string provided. If it's a real HTML file, this is not OK

Comment: @sputnick ok, we get it, your answer is better. Sheesh.